# What does X on a private runway mean?

Tags: non-towered-airport

Does an X at the ends of a private runway mean it's inoperable or does it mean its restricted to the public?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a large flashing "X" placed on a closed runway at Reagan National Airport?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/why-is-a-large-flashing-x-placed-on-a-closed-runway-at-reagan-national-airport)

Comment: @AEhere I think OP is aware that X means "closed" but would like to know if the reason of the closing can be inferred for a **private** runway.

Comment: @QuentinH That is primarily-opinion based as we do not read minds. There is a question to be asked, however, about the suitability and/or legality of closing a working (and potentially active) runway via an X marker, but that is too removed from the OPs wording.

Comment: I agree. Not a duplicate though

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65177/62)

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons why a private runway owner would "X" it would be to indicate that the runway is not in good condition or closed. This can be for a genuine concern or to avoid liability concerns.

Comment: Or just because they don't want you to land on their field.

Comment: @QuentinH Yes, this was addressed in my answer (Closed)